# Accelerated Mobile Pages HTML

Tags: html, amp-html

I'm new to AMP. i've my current website with responsive web design. i don't have separate version for mobile now i want to use AMP. I've pasted amp script to my existing html page and some of my css is not working even on desktop version. do i need separate version of HTML page for AMP?

Comment: _do i need separate version of HTML page for AMP?_ Yes. If you read the documentation and tutorial, that is explained: https://www.ampproject.org/

Comment: i can't see anything regarding my question.

Comment: then how to allocate files ? - Martin Bean

Comment: You create two pages and add canonical links between them: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery

Comment: Thanks @Martin Bean

Answer (score 1):

You cant just convert your site into an AMP just by replacing few tags. your site must follow amp html specification(https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec).

To test that, you can install amp validator chrome extension or by ending your site url by /#development=1 and look into your console.

Here is how it works, google crawler will search for amp in mobile search, if it is found and validates without error then your amp page may show up via link(not your main Web page) in rich search result and top stories in mobile.It will be very fast compared to normal pages but restrictive while developing. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/enhance-amp

If you are not willing to keep separate pages for AMP and non AMP(which is recommended to keep),then you need to compromise on your functionalities.

So, if we take the following URL that has an AMP equivalent: http://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2016/jan/12/sugar-tax-andy-mulligan-liquidator, looking at the source, we see the following link:
 https://amp.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2016/jan/12/sugar-tax-andy-mulligan-liquidator

Answer (score 0):

Amp stands for Accelerated mobile pages. It is a Google initiative for mobile friendly fast web experience. You probably want to convert your existing website into AMP format follow the following link to know how to convert html website into amp
visit : http://itgiggs.in/upgrade-to-amp/